# Custom cookies not created in Firefox - NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firefox, setcookie, httpcookie

This is an ASP.NET MVC application. The cookies are not getting created in Firefox. There is no such issue in Chrome or Edge.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie")
{
   Value = "some_value",
   Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
};

HttpContext.Current?.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

- I have tested this in a fresh installation of Firefox 123.0 64-bit.
- The site is not a local site and it has `https`.
- I have turned off the `Enhanced Tracking Protection` and also added the domain of my website in `Settings > Privacy > Cookies - Manage Exceptions`.

**UPDATE:**

I see this error in browser console for the Ajax POST call - `NS_BINDING_ABORTED`.

This is the JS Method:

```
function redirectTo(obj, url) {
   xhr('/api/MyController/SetCookie', JSON.stringify(obj), () => {
 });
 window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Are you running SSL or testing locally? If the page comes up with a circled "i" beside the padlock you should have the option to explicitly allow cookies for the page. The default cookie settings may not apply if Firefox is "suspicious" about the URL.

Comment: @StevePy Sorry. Missed out that detail. The site is not a local site and it has https. Also I have turned off the `Enhanced Tracking Protection`.

Comment: Hmm, I had a quick check, though using the Response in a controller action and with all browsers including Firefox v123.0. I was able to send a custom cookie without any issue. I'm not sure about `HttpContext.Current.Reponse`. I also tried with just an HTTP site and it was fine. This was with MVC .Net Framework 4.8, ASP.Net Core significantly altered how cookies are handled.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood [here](https://kb.webtrends.com/articles/Information/NS-BINDING-ABORTED-status-message-in-http-debugger/?l=en_US&fs=RelatedArticle), Firefox does this with any page redirection code and if there is another process running already.

So, I have added a delay and it works fine now.

```
function redirectTo(obj, url) {
            xhr('/api/MyController/SetCookie', JSON.stringify(obj), () => {
            });
            //window.location.href = url;            
            setTimeout(function () {                
                window.location.href = url;
            }, 500);    
        }
```